# Global variable not being changed in javascript (Cordova/Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm programming a Phonegap App. My problem is that while modifying a global variable from inside a function, global variable is not being changed.

Function is being fired from a jquery ajax callback. This ajax callback is being fired from Phonegap 'deviceready' event. I'm pretty sure that function is being executed in chrome (using ripple in order to fire 'deviceready') but global variable is not being changed.

This is my 'deviceready' listener:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    storage = window.localStorage;
    LOCALE = "es_ES";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: SERVER,
        data: 'task=' + 'checkRutas' + '&lng=' + LOCALE,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            getNuevasRutas(msg);
        }
    });
```

And this is the function where I'm changing my arrayRutasId array:

```
var SERVER = "http://borrafe.clientes2a.net/XXXXXXX";
var LOCALE = "";
var RUTAVERSIONPREFIX = "rutaversionprefix";
var RUTADATA = "rutaprefix";
arrayRutasId = [];

function getNuevasRutas(respuestas) {
    var nuevasRutas = [];
    var arrayRutas = respuestas['rutas'];
    console.log('Rutas: ' + arrayRutas);
    rutasRestantesNetwork = arrayRutas.length;
    $.each(arrayRutas, function(i, ruta) {
        var version = storage.getItem(RUTAVERSIONPREFIX + ruta.version);
        arrayRutasId.push(RUTADATA + ruta.id);
        console.log(RUTADATA + ruta.id);
        if (storage.getItem(RUTADATA + ruta.id) === null || version < ruta.version) {
            console.log("Por sgunda condición?? " + (version < ruta.version));
            getRuta(ruta.id);
        } else {
            rutasRestantesNetwork--;
        }
    });
    console.log("Hay nuevas rutas en arrayrutasid " + arrayRutasId.length);
    return nuevasRutas;
}
```

All logs are correct and, inside the function 'arrayrutasid' is getting pushed elements correctly. By the way, constants are being correctly accessed inside function!!

-----EDIT-----
I'm trying to read variable from Chrome console.

Comment: Could be a problem with your ajax call, is it returning a correct response? Maybe do console log of "msg" and check if "rutas" is an array.

Comment: nop, it's correct, .each is correctly working, and ruta.id hash good values!

Comment: @pozuelog did you try to console.log() your arrayRutasId.length in some other function after your getNuevasRutas() is done?

Comment: @Regent Yes, and it is ok there. It is not ok when I ask for arrayRutasId in Chrome console!

Comment: @pozuelog maybe the problem is in Chrome console variable watcher, or whatever name it has. If code works as it should, and console.log() gives correct values, than you can just stay it "as is"... Especially because i don't know whether Chorme maintains correctly PhoneGap project or not.

Answer (score 0):

you missing `});`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    storage = window.localStorage;
    LOCALE = "es_ES";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: SERVER,
        data: 'task=' + 'checkRutas' + '&lng=' + LOCALE,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            getNuevasRutas(msg);
        }
    });
});
```